# Every number is the sum of three squares with signs

Tags: arithmetic, sums-of-squares

> **The question.** Can every $n\in \mathbb N$ can be written:
>
> $$n=a^2\pm b^2\pm c^2$$
>
> where $\pm$ are signs of your choice?

We know with [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) that every integer can be written as the sum of four squares.

Plus, with have [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) stated that an integer can not be written as the sum of three squares if, and only if, it is of the form:

$$4^k(8n+7).$$

So we just have to prove (or disprove) it for every number of this form.

I have checked it until $55$, and it seems to work so far. So the number we have to check are [these ones](https://oeis.org/A004215).

For instance:

$$31=6^2-2^2-1^2$$

and

$$39=6^2+2^2-1^2.$$

The issue here is that $a$, $b$ and $c$ can be arbitrarily large. For instance:

$$183=14542^2-14541^2-170^2.$$

So I don't really know how to prove or disprove this result, and I think it could go either way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hang on, it's actually quite simple!

So suppose that we have a number $l$. Suppose that $l=pq$, with $p,q$ having the same parity. That is, both $p$ and $q$ are even, or both $p$ and $q$ are odd.

If this is the case, consider $a= \frac{p+q}{2},  b= \frac{p-q}{2}$. Then, note that $a^2 - b^2 = pq = l$!

For example, $183 = 61 \times 3$, so $a=32$ and $b = 29$, and $32^2-29^2 = 1024 - 841 = 183$.

Now, when can $l$ be written in this form? At least when $l$ is odd, because then you can split it into two odd factors (even if one of those factors is $1$ : for example $7=7 \times 1 = 4^2-3^2$) and carry out the above procedure.

Finally, given an even number, just subtract (or add!) $1^2=1$ to make it an odd number,which can be expressed as a difference of squares.

For example: given $39$, we can write $39=13 \times  3 = 8^2 - 5^2$. Given $78$, we can write $78 = 77 + 1 = 11 \times 7 +1 = 9^2-2^2+1^2$.

What is the reason for so much flexibility? Simple : *$(a^2-b^2)$ has a non-trivial factorization, while $a^2+b^2$ does not.* This is what makes the whole additive theory of squares (and the Waring problem) so interesting and difficult.

Answer (score 11):

$2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2+0^2$ and $2n=(n+1)^2-n^2-1^2$ cover the odd and even cases respectively.

Comment: Or, to avoid use of zeroes, $2n+1=(n+3)^2-(n+2)^2-2^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that every $n$ which is not of the form $4k+2$ can be written in the form $a^2-b^2+0^2$ for some $a$ and $b$. Then $4k+2$ can be written in the form $a^2-b^2-1^2$ for some $a$ and $b$.

(Thanks to John Bentin for pointing out the silly error in my original post.)

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake. It is actually anything not 2 mod 4, will edit.

Comment: @JohnBentin I do not see the connection either... I want to say *odd* number since $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ which is odd.

Comment: @E.Joseph you can also get all multiples of $4$ from $(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2$.